# make 'const' work with the result of type traits

Tags: c++, c++11, std, type-traits

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const int i = 10;
  using Type = typename std::conditional<false, int, int&>::type;
  const Type r = i; // It seems this 'const' does not have any effect.
  std::cout << r << std::endl;
}
```

The above code cannot compile on gcc4.8.1 -std=c++11, and the error message goes as following: "invalid initialization of reference of type 'Type {aka int&}' from expression of type 'const int'. But, it will work if I change the code like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const int i = 10;
  using Type = typename std::conditional<false, const int, const int&>::type;
  Type r = i;
  std::cout << r << std::endl;
}
```

Is there any body can show me the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, the `const` has no effect because it binds to the wrong type: after the reference rather than before.  See https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/DCL33-CPP.+Never+qualify+a+variable+of+reference+type+with+const+or+volatile for some details that may help, but basically:

```
const int& // reference to immutable int
int const& // reference to immutable int
int& const // immutable reference to int
```

Of course, all references are immutable (cannot be reseated), so the last one, which you have, is a bit useless.  It happens because you apply the `const` after the reference has already been applied to the type, which gives you the third example I wrote rather than the first or second.

Comment: (Though typing out `int& const` like that is not valid.  That sort of thing is only allowed when `const` is applied to a typedef or template parameter that happens to be a reference type.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also change

```
  const int i = 10;
```

to

```
  int i = 10;
```

to make it work.

when you say

```
using Type = typename std::conditional<false, int, int&>::type;
```

it is equivalent to:

```
typedef int& Type;
```

When you say

```
const Type r = i;
```

What you are saying is

```
int& const r = i;
```

That's not the same thing as

```
const int& r = i;
```

The difference between those was explained by John Zwinck in his answer.